# traverse neighboring positions from a position of matrix

Tags: java, matrix

im doing it using 8 if to check the positions around a given position
like this.

---

```
//up

if((i-1 >= 0 && i-1 < a.length) && (j >= 0 && j < a[i].length)) {
    if(a[i-1][j]=='A') {
         counter++;
    }
}

//up-right

if((i-1 >= 0 && i-1 < a.length) && (j+1 >= 0 && j+1 < a[i].length)) {
    if(a[i-1][j+1]=='A') {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

---

im trying to do this traversing a matrix or something 
more optimized.

Comment: Just use nested `for` loops for `i` and `j` going from `-1` to `1` and have a check for `i == 0 && j == 0` to continue there.

Comment: A method or a lambda (e.g. BiConsumer or BiFunction https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) comes to mind. You call the thing with your X and Y, it checks the bounds, and it changes "counter", or it just returns 0 or 1 and you add the return value to "counter". If the former, "counter" must be a class variable, or you could put it as the first and only entry of a final int[] array, else the lambda can't access it.